# Can I fix error in submitted conference manuscript after submission due date

Tags: conference, paper-submission

I recently submitted a manuscript to a conference but I found there is a formula error. Now it is about 2 weeks after submission due data. Should I email the chair asking whether I can update? Or should I just wait?

Answer (score 2):

These things vary with the conference, but it is likely that you can make the change now if you contact the program chair or other conference official. There will usually be a later date at which final versions are required for accepted papers.

But if the paper hasn't been accepted yet, then contacting them might prevent a rejection. In any case someone like the "program chair" will give you the necessary feedback.

You might help yourself a bit if you prepare an explanation of where and why a change is necessary so that if a paper is already with a reviewer then they can quickly catch up to the current version.